# How to convert a hexadecimal value contained in a char (byte) to an integer?

Tags: c++, c, hex, type-conversion

I just want to know how to convert an hexadecimal value contained in a char (byte) into an integer. I want to convert the color buffer from a .bmp file which is of course in hexadecimal and convert it in integers.

For example :

```
char rgb_hexa[3] = {0xA8, 0xF4, 0xD3};
```

After conversion :

```
int rgb_int[3] = {168, 244, 211};
```

I always tried to use strtol but it seems to only works with char *. I tried to do the following test but it does not work :

```
char    src_hexa_red = 0xA8;
char    src_hexa_green = 0xF4;
char    src_hexa_blue = 0xD3;

std::cout << "R=" << strtol(&src_hexa_red, (char**)NULL, 16) << ", G="
      << strtol(&src_hexa_green, (char**)NULL, 16) << ", B="
      << strtol(&src_hexa_blue, (char**)NULL, 16) << std::endl;
```

Does anyone can help me please ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. The integer literals `0xA8` and `168` are the same, it's just different way of writing the exact same thing to make things easier for the programmer. The compiler puts the same **binary** representation in the compiled binary.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - you will need to cast to unsigned - 168 is more than what will fit in a `char`.

Comment: @user93353 It depends.  If you compile with the `/J` option with MSVC, `168` will fit in a `char`.  More generally, though, you will either have to convert to `unsigned char`, _or_ `&` with `0xFF`.  The latter will work even on machines with 9 bit bytes (but I don't know of any where plain `char` is signed).

Comment: @JamesKanze True, /J makes the default char unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    rgb_int[i] = (unsigned char)rgb_hexa[i];
```

`char` is an integer type in C & C++ just like `short`, `int` and `long`. It's just the smallest integer type. Mostly, `char` is signed & the maximum which can fit is 127. So if the hex value was below or equal to 127, you wouldn't have to do anything. However, in this case the hex values you have are > 127 - hence you would have to cast them to unsigned to get the value you want.

Note that both the statements are identical to the compiler.

```
char rgb_hexa[3] = {0xA8, 0xF4, 0xD3};
char rgb_hexa[3] = {168, 244, 211};
```

You could have even used octal if you wanted

```
char rgb_hexa[3] = {0250, 0364, 0323};
```

It's all the same.

Comment: unsigned char was the answer for me. Did not realise char is signed. This question shouldn't have downvotes.. It's a real struggle for beginners...

Answer (score 6):

A single `char` never contains hexadecimal.  Nor decimal, for
that matter.  Strictly speaking, a `char` contains an integral
*value*; the C++ standard requires it to use a binary
representation for the value.  The value can be interpreted as
a character, but this is not always the case; there are contexts
where the integral value is used directly.

Hexadecimal and decimal are just ways of representing the value
in text format.  They only have meaning when dealing with text.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the char array are already in a binary form, so you can cast them to an int, if you need them as such.

```
int v = (int)rgb_hexa[0];
```

You should be aware though that using signed char they will be sign extendend.
So `0xFA` becomes `0xFFFFFFFA` when converted to an int.

If you want to keep the values then you should use `unsigned char` and `unsigned int` which makes it `0x000000FA` depending on how you want to use the values.

```
int v0 = (int)a[1];   <-- sign extended
unsigned int v1 = (unsigned int)a[1];    <-- sign extended
unsigned int v1 = (unsigned int)((unsigned char *)a)[1];   <-- not sign extended
```

Comment: Plain `char` may be signed or unsigned.  For historical reasons, it usually (but not always) defaults to signed, but most compilers have an option to make it unsigned (which you should probably use---signed characters is a horrible hack).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any conversion because hexa/decimal are just ways to represent values.

For example 0xA8 in hexadecimal is the same value as 180 in decimal and 250 in octal. As in languages for example, "two", "deux" and "dois" represent all the same number (2).

In your case if you want to print the values do the following:

```
short y = (short) x & 0x00FF; // x is the char you want to print
    cout << "Value (decimal): " << y;
    cout << "Value (hexa): " << hex << y;
    cout << "Value (oct): " << oct << y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char rgb_hexa[3] = {0xA8, 0xF4, 0xD3};
    int rgb_int[3]  = {0,};
    int i = 0;
    for( i = 0 ; i < 3 ;i++)
        rgb_int[i] = (unsigned char)rgb_hexa[i];

    for( i = 0 ; i < 3 ;i++)
        printf("%d ",rgb_int[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

pretty straight forward ..

Answer (score 0):

For type conversion, there is [static_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/):

```
unsigned char source = 168;   // note that this has for compiler same meaning as:
// unsigned char source = 0xA8;   // because data is stored in binary anyway

unsigned int dest = static_cast<int>(source);   // the conversion

std::cout << source << std::endl;
```

`dest` and `source` have same binary meaning, but they are of a different type.

I've used unsigned types, because signed char stores usually values from -127 to 127, see [limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).